# Flutter Theme Error Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Tags: flutter, themes

I am new at flutter. i am getting this error

======== Exception caught by widgets library =============

The following assertion was thrown building Consumer(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope]):
Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

My code is :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppThemeNotifier>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AppThemeNotifier value, Widget child) {
        int themeMode = value.themeMode();
        themeData = AppTheme.getThemeFromThemeMode(themeMode);
        customAppTheme = AppTheme.getCustomAppTheme(themeMode);
        return MaterialApp(
```

AppThemeNotifier.dart

```
/*
* File : App Theme Notifier (Listener)
* Version : 1.0.0
* */

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AppThemeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {

  int _themeMode = 1;

  AppThemeNotifier() {
    init();
  }

  init() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int data =  sharedPreferences.getInt("themeMode");
    if(data==null)
      _themeMode = 1;
    else
      _themeMode = data;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  themeMode() => _themeMode;

  notify(){
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> updateTheme(int themeMode) async {
    this._themeMode = themeMode;
    notifyListeners();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setInt("themeMode", themeMode);
  }
}
```

Comment: This code does not help finding out the problem.

Comment: Added file details